# Number of schedules that do not repeat a matchup

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

### Background

There are *n* teams such that *n* is even. A *matchup* is a pair of two distinct teams where order does not matter so that `(A,B)` and `(B,A)` are equivalent. A *schedule* is comprised of all *n* teams in $\frac n2$ matchups. For example, the following is a possible schedule of 8 teams labeled A ... H:
`{(A,B) (C,D) (E,F) (G,H)}`

### Question

From the set of all possible schedules, one is chosen at random. How many schedules in the set of all possible schedules share no matchups with this random schedule?

### Progress I've Made

The size of the set of schedules is `(n-1)(n-3)(n-5)...(3)(1)`. For `n = 6` there are 15 possible schedules. I've listed these by hand. By inspection, 8 of the 15 possible schedules would share no matchup with a random schedule. However, I have not been able to hit upon an equation that would describe this for all *n*.

### Areas of Inspection

I've attempted to use derangements and other variation of the principle of inclusion-exclusion, but either this is the wrong approach or I'm not using the principles correctly. I read about orthogonal latin squares but am unsure if they apply to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use Inclusion-Exclusion.
For example  for six people, three pairs:
Start with $1×3×5=15$
Subtract $3\choose1$ times $1×3$, which is nine.
Add $3\choose2$ times $1$, which is three.
Subtract $3\choose3$ times $1$, which is one.
Total $15-9+3-1=8$

Answer (score 1):

[OEIS A053871](http://oeis.org/A053871) gives the following recursion:

$$a(0) = 1; a(1) = 0; a(n) = 2 (n - 1)*(a(n - 1) + a(n - 2))$$

From the comments there:

> The formula is given directly by the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.
>
> The first term includes all pairings, the second term excludes all pairings containing each pair, the third term includes all pairings containing each pair of pairs, and so on.